# Debian editor with syntax highlight for DOT language

Tags: debian, editors, syntax-highlighting, graphviz

I'm looking for a Debian editor with syntax highlight for the DOT language.

Answer (score 8):

Vim has this built-in: https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/syntax/dot.vim. Mode for Emacs, can be installed from MELPA: https://github.com/ppareit/graphviz-dot-mode